# Stack Navigation Using React Native leading to undefined is not object error

Tags: reactjs, react-native, react-navigation, react-native-navigation

I am quite new at react native and am trying to figure navigation out any help/guidance anyone could offer would be greatly appreciated. so i have this links screen and I am trying to navigate to a different screen for this example I have made a screen called trial (Code not included) that just has a simple flex view in it with a background. However, I am very confused about how stack transitioning works. Everything I saw online uses props.this.navigation.navigate('') however I want to have my stack navigator on a seperate js file instead of having all my windows in the same file. So for this example i am trying to navigate from LinksScreen to Trial I will be adding more windows so I am not looking to use a switch navigator.

On a side note (idk if this is that relevant) The Links screen is already embedded into a tab navigator code found below:

Once again thank you for any possible help.

Screen:

```
import MyStackNavigator from '../navigation/StackNavigator';
import { createAppContainer } from 'react-navigation';

const AppContainer = createAppContainer(MyStackNavigator);

export default function LinksScreen() {

  return (
    <ScrollView style={styles.container}>

        <Button style = {styles.button}
          onPress={() => AppContainer.props.navigation.navigate('Trial')}
          title="Make a Plan"
        />
```

.... Remainder

Stack Navigation Class:

```
import { createStackNavigator } from 'react-navigation-stack';
import LinksScreen from '../screens/LinksScreen';
import Trial from '../screens/Trial';

const MyStackNavigator = createStackNavigator(
    {
      Trial: Trial,
      LinksScreen: LinksScreen,
    },
);
```

Tab Navigation:

```
const LinksStack = createStackNavigator(
  {
    Links: LinksScreen,
  },
  config
);

LinksStack.navigationOptions = {
  tabBarLabel: 'Workouts',
  tabBarIcon: ({ focused }) => (
    <TabBarIcon focused={focused} name={Platform.OS === 'ios' ? 'ios-fitness' : 'md-fitness'} />
  ),
};

LinksStack.path = '';

.....

const tabNavigator = createBottomTabNavigator({
  HomeStack,
  LinksStack,
  SettingsStack,
});

tabNavigator.path = '';

export default tabNavigator;
```

Main App.js

```
import AppNavigator from './navigation/AppNavigator';

export default function App(props) {
  const [isLoadingComplete, setLoadingComplete] = useState(false);

  if (!isLoadingComplete && !props.skipLoadingScreen) {
    return (
      <AppLoading
        startAsync={loadResourcesAsync}
        onError={handleLoadingError}
        onFinish={() => handleFinishLoading(setLoadingComplete)}
      />
    );
  } else {
    return (
      <View style={styles.container}>
        {Platform.OS === 'ios' && <StatusBar barStyle="default" />}
        <AppNavigator />
      </View>
    );
  }
}
```

....

Comment: im very confused with what you want, generally its a good idea to keep all your stack navigators in the App.js

Comment: I basically have a tab navigator and am trying to use a stack navigato within those tabs to access other pages